# C++ Graph using a vector of unordered_map, adding random data when accessed like graph[i][j]

Tags: c++, graph, unordered-map

I am trying to go through a txt file with facebook data from 2009 and represent people as vertices on a graph, and friendships as edges. The code to make the graph works perfectly. I used it to calculate the average number of friends that people in this data set had. But when trying to find the average of the average of their friends things get weird. When I try to get the number of friends of a certain friend, the size of that table drastically increases (one time it went from 10 to 988) it keeps doing this until I get a bad_alloc error and im not sure why. How can I access an element without it changing the graph?

```
 while (FacebookInfo >> V1 >> V2 >> garbage) {

        unordered_map<int, int>::const_iterator got = graph[V1].find(V2);

        if (got == graph[V1].end()) {
            graph[V1].insert(make_pair(V2, (int)graph[V1].size()));
            graph[V2].insert(make_pair(V1, (int)graph[V2].size()));
        }
    }


//This is the loop that breaks it
    for (int i = 1; i < 63732; i++) {

        int averageFriendsOfFriendsForV = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].size(); j++) {
            int friendOfFriend = graph[graph[i][j]].size(); //this is the line specifically the graph[i][j]
            averageFriendsOfFriendsForV += friendOfFriend;
        }

        averageFriendsOfFriendsForV /= graph[i].size();

        totalAvg += averageFriendsOfFriendsForV;
    }
```

Edit: Figured it out, still not sure why it would add data but

```
for(auto& j : graph[i]){
    int friendOfFriend = graph[j.first].size();
    etc...
}
```

fixes it

Comment: `63732` seems kind of arbitrary. If this isn't just for a quick stress test, you should turn the number into a constant with a descriptive name. Those that follow you will thank you. Or at least not use your name as a curse word.

Comment: ahh thank you Buddhima, that makes sense! And 63732 is how many elements are in the data set, Ill change it to a variable to explain that thanks for the advice!

Comment: Yes, it is because the keys of `graph[i]` are not necessarily integers from `0` to `graph[i].size() - 1`. You should iterate over actual keys.

Comment: @JonathonFord A map mysteriously getting more elements is a sign that you are using the map's `operator [ ]` to search the map.  If the entry is not found, the map will add the entry.  This is a common mistake people make when using `operator[ ]` for map searches.   Use the map's `find()` function if your goal is to ensure that entries are not added inadvertently,.

Comment: And if it turns out the keys are ARE nicely sequential and not sparse, an array or `vector` might be a better choice. Less overhead and with integer keys, array or `vector` would have quicker look-up.

Answer (score 0):

This always trips me up, if you take a look at the [index operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) for `std::unordered_map`, you'll find that it will:

```
... perform an insertion if such key does not already exist.
```

So in that loop on the line you suspect:

```
int friendOfFriend = graph[graph[i][j]].size();
```

you're probably creating new entries every time which eventually becomes impossible. If you post a bit more code it may be easier to diagnose (since I'm not sure what type `graph` is in the first place).

Instead of using the `operator[]`, it might be good to do something like:

```
auto friend = graph.find(i);
if (friend == graph.end()) return;
auto other_friend = graph.find(friend->second);
if (other_friend == graph.end()) return;
```

or something along those lines where you explicitly check for the existence of the friend.